# javascript regex to detect if inline javascript or external script

Tags: javascript, regex

I wrote a function that takes an array of data and appends the html or executes the inline js or external js.  Is there a cleaner way to detect the script src, maybe using a single regex instead of the conditionals?

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/nfrobmxt/

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head></head>

  <body>

<div id="content"></div>

<script>

// Execute inline js.
function _append(selector, arr) {
    var content = arr;
    for(var i = 0; i< content.length; i++) {
        var _content = content[i];
        var js = _content.indexOf('script');
        var src = _content.indexOf('src=');
        // Script tag.
        if(js > -1) {
            var inline = '';
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            if(src > -1) {
                script.src = 'http://chrismills.la/test.js';
            } else {
                _content.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gi, function(){
                    inline += arguments[1] + '\n';
                });
                script.text = inline;
            }
            selector.appendChild(script);
        } else {
            selector.innerHTML += _content;
        }
    }
}
// Selector - div or tag.
var selector = document.body;

// String with inline javascript.
var arr = [];
// Inline javascript.
arr.push('<script>alert("inline javascript");</\script>');
arr.push('<script>alert("more inline javascript");</\script>');
// External script.
arr.push('<script src="http://chrismills.la/test.js"></\script>');
// HTML.
arr.push('<p>Content.</p>');
arr.push('<p>More Content.</p><p>More Content 2.</p>');

_append(selector, arr);
    </script>

      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You dont really need a regex, you can just find the scripts with `document.getElementByTagName('script')` and check if they have a `src`

Comment: the scripts aren't loaded or executed yet at that part of the function.  I am detecting how to load them, inline vs external.

Comment: So you want to append the data from the array element if it's `HTML` but if it has inline javascript, you want to execute the javascript instead? Not sure, but doesn't appending the `HTML` properly as a tag not execute the inline script or external script tag? I've seen people inject javascript this way and it seems to work fine.

Comment: it works fine as is, just wondering if there is a way to get rid of the condition in the js to differentiate between inline and external js.  Also need a regex to get the js source dynamically from the array.

Answer (score 1):

Not an ideal solution but I was able to do it all as one function.

```
// Append js and html.
function _append(selector, arr) {
    var content = arr;
    for(var i = 0; i< content.length; i++) {
        var _content = content[i];
        var js = _content.indexOf('script');
        if(js > -1) {
            // Script tag.
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            var regex = /<script.*?src="(.*?)"/gmi;
            var url = regex.exec(_content);
            var inline = '';
            if(url) {
                script.src = url[1];
            }
            _content.replace(/<script[^>]*>([\s\S]*?)<\/script>/gi, function(){
                inline += arguments[1] + '\n';
            });
            script.text = inline;
            selector.appendChild(script);
        } else {
            // html content.
            selector.innerHTML += _content;
        }
    }
}
// Selector - div or tag.
var selector = document.body;

// String with inline javascript.
var arr = [];
// Inline javascript.
arr.push('<script>alert("inline javascript");</\script>');
arr.push('<script>alert("more inline javascript");</\script>');
// External script.
arr.push('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://chrismills.la/test.js"></\script>');
// HTML.
arr.push('<p>Content.</p>');
arr.push('<p>More Content.</p><p>More Content 2.</p>');

_append(selector, arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Jon Snow's comment suggests a simpler solution. Example:

```
var counter = 0;
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script');
Array.prototype.forEach.call(scripts, function(script, index){
  if( !script.hasAttribute("src") ){counter++;}
});
console.log(scripts.length +" total script tags. "+counter + " inline script tags found" )
```